# Part identification: SOT753/TSOP5 marked E:I

Tags: identification, components

I need your help to identify the part on the attached picture.

I've already identified it as an SOT753 / TSOP 5 part but couldn't find the manufacturer or a source for it. It comes from a board which I'm asked to rebuild due to data loss. So sadly there isn't anymore information about the function of the board.

My guess it is some kind of switch or of a similar function.

The marking is E : I with a third dot beneath the colon for lead free.

Maybe someone knows that.

[image: 1st Picture]

Edit:

- The red points mark the power pins.  Due to a short on the board I don't know which is which.
- Orange is connected to one power rail as well.
- Green  goes to one input pin of a GAL22V10.

I'm not that comfortable with posting a picture a lot bigger than this.

[image: 2nd Picture]

Comment: Anything you can say about pinout? Can you trace what pins are power/gnd and where the other ones go? Maybe show a greater part of the circuit so we can guess the function? It's not much to go with. Please, give as much info as you can

Comment: @Ilya I've edited my post and hope to answer some of your questions.

Comment: My best guess so far would be something from the 74(LVC)1Gxx series; the power/ground pins seem to match. I haven't found a single opamp with matching power pin locations. Another guess is that it's not made by TI, the few parts I've looked at have 3 letter markings on this package, but NXP/Diodes inc. seem to use 2 letter codes.

Comment: I had similar logic, it feels like some kind of an op amp with the one on the right as a follower with IN- and VOUT tied together, but I couldn't find a single op amp to match the exact pinout

Comment: It appears that the green node can go to an IO pin of the GAL22V10, not necessarily an input pin. If it is configured as an output pin, it would match the general structure of the 74xxx1Gxx devices, as those tend to have inputs on pins 1 and 2.